# How to handle Null value in Data Link Layer?

Tags: c#

I'm working in Asp.net WCF. I'm displaying a table in front end, with the data taken from back end. One of the column having datatype date, contains Null value in backend. When i try to run the solution it displays error page because of the Null value, for the column. How can i avoid this error ?

Comment: How are you binding the data to the table. Can you show us your code ?

Comment: You need to edit your question so it is answerable. Unless you do this fast, in it's current state it will be closed very shortly because there is not enough information to answer it. Please post the code line which is causing the error, and the actual error message including stack trace

Comment: ObjUnutilizedOwnershipEntities.Dt_VisaValidFrom = Convert.ToDatetime(osqlDataReader["Dt_VisaValidFrom"].ToString());

Comment: above line shows error as 'Dt_VisaValidFrom' column contains null value in DB..

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [**SqlDataReader.IsDBNull Method**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.isdbnull.aspx)

1. Check whether the database field contains **`null`** value
2. Handle it with **`String.Empty`**

Here is an sample that I have used

```
logSource = (!reader.IsDBNull(0)) ? reader.GetString(0).Trim() : "";
```

From your comments,

```
ObjUnutilizedOwnershipEntities.Dt_VisaValidFrom = (!IsDBNull(osqlDataReader["Dt_VisaValidFrom"])) 
                                                ? Convert.ToDatetime(osqlDataReader["Dt_VisaValidFrom"].ToString()) 
                                                : "";
```